# How to split folders of a git repo into separate branches?

Tags: git, tfs

I've been charged with converting our TFS repo over to git (via [this thingy](https://github.com/spraints/git-tfs/)).  The TFS repo is set up thus:

```
$/root
    /branch1
    /branch2
    /branch3
```

...etc, with the TFS branches appearing in the imported git repo as folders.  Is there a way of splitting each branchX off as a branch of the git repo, making the contents the new root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a tool called [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree) doing exactly that.