# Split Up Folders in a git repository into separate branches

Tags: git, git-subtree

I have finally migrated our CVS repository to git. Unfortunately we didn't use branches in CVS but different versions/branches were separated into different subdirectories.

I.E. we have the following directory structure:

```
/root
    /lib
    /tools
    /src
        /v1.0
        /v2.0
        /v3.5
```

Is there a way to separate the 3 versions in the src subdirectory into separate branches instead of keeping the directory for each version?

I have found the same question here on Stack Overflow [Question 4877053](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877053/how-to-split-folders-of-a-git-repo-into-separate-branches), where the use of git-subtree is proposed, but even after reading the manual for git-subtree, I didn't understand how to use it to solve my problem.

Can someone give me a more detailed explanation or even another solution?

I'm quite new to git, perhaps that's why I didn't understand the subtree manual ;-)

Thanks very much for all your anwers!

Comment: Do you have commit history associated with the different version directories? When you migrated the CVS repo to git, do you now have a history that you wish to keep? I'm pretty sure you can split those directories off using a combination of `git filter-branch` and `git merge`, but it's hard to say for certain without knowing what you want to keep or what you want the final repository to look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends what you want left in the repository afterwards.

If you want three branches, `v1.0`, `v2.0`, `v3.5`, all with structure like this:

```
/root
    /lib
    /tools
    /src
```

then yes, I'm pretty sure you can do that. You'll end up with something like this in terms of branch structure:

```
-- A -- B -- Current 
              | 
              |--- v1.0
              |--- v2.0
              |--- v3.5
```

`A`, `B`, `Current` being commits you've committed since you migrated to git, and where `v1.0`, `v2.0` and `v3.5` are essentially "dead-end" branches. You could do some fancy things if you want to get a branch structure more like:

```
-- v1.0 --- v2.0 --- v3.5 -- A -- B -- Current
```

That is, separate `v1.0`, `v2.0`, and `v3.5` into their own branches, then rebase `v1.0` onto `v2.0`, `v2.0` onto `v3.5`, and `v3.5` onto the first commit in the current version.

But I'm not sure exactly what you want to do.

---

> Is there a way to separate the 3 versions in the src subdirectory into separate branches instead of keeping the directory for each version?

Yes, I'm pretty sure you can do this. My methodology is a little ... convoluted, I'll admit, but here goes. **Please**, be careful and **read the man pages** - the following commands *probably* won't screw everything up, but use at your own risk.

1. `git checkout -b v1.0` - get onto a new branch.
2. Remove everything except `v1.0`. There are a few ways to do this. This question has some methods for removal of everything except ; I couldn't get them working for me, it might work better for you.

   ```
   `git filter-branch --index-filter "git rm -r -f --cached --ignore-unmatch src/v2.0" --prune-empty -f`
   ```

   This will remove `src/v2.0` **and all associated history** from the branch. `-f` isn't necessary for this filter; but `git-filter-branch` does some sort of backup (read the man page?) and it might spit errors. It defiantly will the second time you try `git filter-branch`.

   Repeat this to remove `src/v3.5` as well.

   This will leave you with `src/v1.0`. You possibly want to shift the source from `src/v1.0` to `src`; you could run a `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter` (read the man page) to get you a directory structure `/v1.0-files` (contains nothing but the files from subdirectory `v1.0`; has moved contents from `v1.0` to `root`), and then look at the examples in the `man git-filter-branch` page (specifically the bottom example) to shift files into a subdirectory. That might be overkill, and you'd then need to merge *that* into a branch containing all the other stuff that `git filter-branch --subdirectory` culled; a simple `mv v1.0/* .` might work, but you'd then have another commit in your history. I don't know what you'd prefer.

   So now you've got `v1.0` in it's own branch. Yay!
3. Repeat for `v2.0` and `v3.5`.

I'm afraid I can't see this doing anything but giving you ... "odd" history, though. Presumably `v2.0` has, essentially, `v1.0` + improvements; the structure I've listed above (three "dead-end" branches) shows `v2.0` and `v3.5` don't build on the previous versions. I'm not entirely sure what kind of history you have, if this is an issue, etc etc.

Because you've got `v1.0`, `v2.0` and `v3.5` in their own little branches, you can `git merge` them or `git rebase` etc etc, if you'd prefer a nicer looking history.

Hopefully this gives you a little bit to think about; like I said, **please read the man pages**. :)